# How to prevent undesired queries in a repository

Tags: c#, repository, expression

I have a repository class which takes QueryConstraints object as a parameter to query the data store and return an IEnumerable of desired entity. The repository is supposed to prevent queries which may take too long to process. The QueryConstraints is as follow:

```
public class QueryConstraints<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> WhereClause { get; }
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> SortClause { get; }
    public int Skip {get;}
    public int Take {get;}
    ...
    some other fields
}
```

When a client creates a QueryConstraints it should assign expressions to WhereClause and SortClause properties and pass the object to the Find() method of the repository where the expressions are to be inspected and processed.

**My question is:** 
I know that it is possible to use expression tree to inspect the body of the expression. However I don't know how to do it exactly to achieve my purpose. For example I want to prevent a query which has no index available for its fields. How should i do that?

Comment: The `SortClause` seems to be "strange" (`OrderBy` is `<T, TKey>`, not `<T, bool>`, unless you want to be able to sort only for boolean columns). For the main question, yes, you'll have to parse the `Expression<>`. You'll clearly need a list of indexed properties to compare with (normally in the mapping of the DB this information isn't present. You'll have to add it manually somewhere)

Comment: As a sidenote, you have to decide if you want all the conditions to be on indexed fields (doable) or you want to have at least one condition on an indexed field. Example: `Where(x => x.Name == "Foo" && x.Sex == 'M')`, where `Name` is indexed and `Sex` isn't.

Comment: In general, you'll have to subclass `ExpressionVisitor` and override the `VisitMember` method...